# How to apply CSS styles in eclipse 3.x RCP?

Tags: themes, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to use CSS in eclipse 3.x. The CCS file is defined via the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme` extension and is loaded via this code in the `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor`

```
public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer)
{
    super.initialize(configurer);

    BundleContext context = Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getBundleContext();
    ServiceReference serviceRef = context.getServiceReference(IThemeManager.class.getName());
    IThemeManager themeManager = (IThemeManager) context.getService(serviceRef);
    final IThemeEngine engine = themeManager.getEngineForDisplay(Display.getCurrent());
    engine.setTheme("com.mycompany.rcp.test.theme", true);

}
```

It does work but there are many 'Discouraged access' warnings like this one: `Discouraged access: The type 'IThemeEngine' is not API (restriction on required library 'D:\Workspaces\Indu4.0-Oxygen\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins\org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.11.0.v20170312-2302.jar')`

Is there a better way to handle themes and styles in eclipse 3.x apps?

Comment: hi @paul. I am also trying to add theme in eclipse rcp 3.x. Could you give any link to follow?

Answer (score 1):

A number of e4 APIs such as `IThemeManager` are still marked as 'not API' because they have still not been finalized.

You just have to put up with the discouraged access warning or you can suppress the warning with

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
```

you have to put this at the class level to suppress the warning for the import.